# How to update a storageClassName in a statefulset?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to k8's and trying to update storageClassName in a StatefulSet.(from default to default-t1 only change in the yaml)

I tried running `kubectl apply -f test.yaml`

The only difference between 1st and 2nd Yaml(one using to apply update) is storageClassName: default-t1 instead of default

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  serviceName: "nginx"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: default
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Every-time I try to update it I get `The StatefulSet "web" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden`

What am I missing or what steps should I take to do this?

Answer (score 10):

There's no easy way as far as I know but it's possible.

1. Save your current StatefulSet configuration to yaml file:

```
kubectl get statefulset some-statefulset -o yaml > statefulset.yaml
```

2. Change `storageClassName` in `volumeClaimTemplate` section of StatefulSet configuration saved in yaml file
3. Delete StatefulSet without removing pods using:

```
kubectl delete statefulset some-statefulset --cascade=orphan
```

4. Recreate StatefulSet with changed StorageClass:

```
kubectl apply -f statefulset.yaml
```

5. For each Pod in StatefulSet, first delete its PVC (it will get stuck in terminating state until you delete the pod) and then delete the Pod itself

After deleting each Pod, StatefulSet will recreate a Pod (and since there is no PVC) also a new PVC for that Pod using changed StorageClass defined in StatefulSet.

Answer (score 1):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  serviceName: "nginx"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: <storage class name>
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

in the above file add storage class and you can apply it like.

kubectl apply -f .yaml

Comment: my yaml is exactly like the one you added above. when I use it to update 'replicas' .. 'template' or 'updateStrategy' it works fine but i still get the same error when updating storageClassName... I just needed to know if this is possible or not at this point. As from the error message looks like it isnt . 
see command and console output.
```kubectl apply -f test.yaml
service/nginx unchanged
statefulset.apps/web configured```

Comment: it worked there was no changes in service so service unchanged and change in deployment so it configured as per new argument.

Answer (score 0):

First line of StatefulSet shoud define an "apiVersion", you can see example here [statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/). Please add it in first line:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
```

Could you show me output of your 'www' PVC file?

```
kubectl get pvc www -o yaml
```

In PVC you have field "storageClassName", which should be set on your StorageClass you want to use, so in your case it would be:

```
storageClassName: default-t1
```